# In AKS how do I limit access to the cluster DNS to internal VMs

Tags: azure, dns, kubernetes

My scenario is pretty simple, but my google-fu is either not working, or I'm not understanding the documentation correctly.

We have an AKS cluster and we have windows services running on IIS in another vnet running on some VMs.  Converting those windows services to run on K8S is not an option.

How can we open up a dns name on the AKS cluster so that our Windows service can call apis for services that exist on the K8S cluster, yet at the same time NOT allow any access to that cluster from the public.

I tried making a VPN gateway but it wanted a public ip.
I tried looking into external-dns but that also looks like its public only.

Our K8S cluster does have public access through an api-gateway, however, we would rather that the "internal" calls not go through the entire auth process on every call.

Comment: You can try to peering the two vnet and then configure a private DNS server in the vnet. So you can access via the DNS name without through the Internet.

Comment: @CharlesXu-MSFT I want to make use of the DNS name created by K8S.

Comment: If you do not want to through the Internet. It seems you cannot make use of the DNS name created by K8s. The DNS name created by K8s is also associated with the public IP in Azure.

Comment: The dns name created by kube-dns when you define a service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a vnet peering or vnet site-to-site connection depending on your setup.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2017/06/28/step-by-step-configuring-a-site-to-site-vpn-gateway-between-azure-and-on-premise/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-peering-overview

Comment: not sure what exactly are you asking, aks name - is the master name, its not on your vnet, so it cannot work inside your vnet.

Comment: The dns name created by kube-dns when you define a service.

Comment: that dns name is not exposed outside the cluster, but if you create a internal load balancer or use network policy to give pods ips from the vnet this will work

Comment: Just to confirm and make this more complete, I also need to set up a private dns zone.

Comment: that is if you want dns.